# Flutter: How to turn on screen when locked?

Tags: android, flutter, lockscreen

Let's say I have a working background service that logs notifications; How can I wake up a locked screen and display a message or even better a flutter scaffold?

I'v tried the recent Local Notifications and added all necessary entries to the Android Manifest. It works except when the screen is off.

I'v tried these in the AndroidManifest with no success:

```
<application
    <activity....
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
   </activity>
   ....
</application>
            ...
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```